Programmatically connect to SSRS other than using web services
I have been creating desktop apps and console apps that connect to SSRS for years.
The challenge is that they use web services. 2 web services exactly
'http://myserver:800/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl
'http://myserver:800/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl

The last time I created one was .Net Framework 4.~ and this has sufficed to now.
I need to make a new console app to accomplish a new set of requirements.
As I start trying make this all happens it really seems like I am swimming uphill.  VS Really wants me to make a .NET Standard app.
I tried creating a .NET Standard console app and it complains that it can not load system.web.services.
this is a .Net Framework library and I do not find any information on what might have replaced it in .Net Standard.
All the reading I have done laments on how antiquated webservices are.
I do NOT want to use the SSRS ReportViewer Control.
I do want to programmatically

Connect to SSRS
Open a report definition
Pass in parameters
Get back a stream of my choosing (it is most often a pdf file)

Is there something newer than the 2 webservices?
Is there something about the current web services that prevents them from becoming simple REST apis that could be used by Standard?   I know we pass in types, but those could be converted to JSON? No?
what if I wanted to connect from Linux, is that possible?
**My Question is  :  I am currently using the old web services approach to programmatically connect to SSRS.  IS THERE A NEWER, PREFERRED way? **

I still use the asmx web services as they are supported for all non-EOL versions of SSRS. If you are using >= SSRS 2017, then you are in luck and can use the new rest apis.
Description of Restful Api
SSRS 2017 SwaggerDocs

Not sure how these have escaped my googling. Thank you!
